# How to add input fields on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function add() {
  var new_chq_no = parseInt($('#total_chq').val()) + 1;
  var new_input = "<input type='text' id='new_" + new_chq_no + "'>";
  $('#new_chq').html(new_input);
}

function remove() {
  var last_chq_no = $('#total_chq').val();
  if (last_chq_no > 1) {
    $('#new_' + last_chq_no).append('');
    $('#total_chq').val(last_chq_no - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="remove()">remove</button>
<div id="new_chq"></div>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">
```

its adding input fields one time and on second click its not adding anything and remove button is not working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/592/)**.

You have to use `.append()` instead of `.html()` when appending elements :

```
$('#new_chq').append(new_input);
```

It will be better to attach the event in your JS code like :

```
$('.add').on('click', add);
$('.remove').on('click', remove);
```

**NOTE 1:** Don't forget to increment the counter `#total_chq` :

```
$('#total_chq').val(new_chq_no);
```

**NOTE 2:** You've to use `.remove()` if you want to remove the element.

```js
$('.add').on('click', add);
$('.remove').on('click', remove);

function add() {
  var new_chq_no = parseInt($('#total_chq').val()) + 1;
  var new_input = "<input type='text' id='new_" + new_chq_no + "'>";

  $('#new_chq').append(new_input);

  $('#total_chq').val(new_chq_no);
}

function remove() {
  var last_chq_no = $('#total_chq').val();

  if (last_chq_no > 1) {
    $('#new_' + last_chq_no).remove();
    $('#total_chq').val(last_chq_no - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button class="add">Add</button>
<button class="remove">remove</button>
<div id="new_chq"></div>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the snippet, hope this is what you are looking for :D

```js
function add(){
      var new_chq_no = parseInt($('#total_chq').val())+1;
      var new_input="<input type='text' id='new_"+new_chq_no+"'>";
      $('#new_chq').append(new_input);
      $('#total_chq').val(new_chq_no)
    }
    function remove(){
      var last_chq_no = $('#total_chq').val();
      if(last_chq_no>1){
        $('#new_'+last_chq_no).remove();
        $('#total_chq').val(last_chq_no-1);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <button onclick="remove()">remove</button>
  <div id="new_chq"></div>
  <input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.add').on('click', add);
$('.remove').on('click', remove);

function add() {
  var new_chq_no = parseInt($('#total_chq').val()) + 1;
  var new_input = "<input type='text' id='new_" + new_chq_no + "'>";

  $('#new_chq').append(new_input);

  $('#total_chq').val(new_chq_no);
}

function remove() {
  var last_chq_no = $('#total_chq').val();

  if (last_chq_no > 1) {
    $('#new_' + last_chq_no).remove();
    $('#total_chq').val(last_chq_no - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button class="add">Add</button>
<button class="remove">remove</button>
<div id="new_chq"></div>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question with code, try to explain it a little bit.